# jQuery Plugin Odd this Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, this

I'm working on my first plugin.  It converts a standard `select` element into a stylized `div`.  The code works just fine if I call a jQuery function that gathers all my `$(".special_selctor")` `selects` and does the logic, so I decided to pull that logic into a plugin so I could just directly call `stylize` on the `select` rather than iterating over all my special classes.

Here's a snipped of the code from the NON-plugin ( `$(this)` is an instance of a `select` marked with my custom class):

```
var tmp = '';
tmp += '<div class="jm-select"' + (f_width ? ' style="width:' + (parseInt(f_width) + 7 + 32) + 'px;"' : '') + '>';
tmp += '<a ' + (f_width ? ' style="width:' + f_width + 'px;"' : '') + ' href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="display">' + display + '</span><span class="arrow"></span></a>';
tmp += '<div class="options"' + (f_width ? ' style="width:' + (parseInt(f_width) + 7) + 'px;"' : '') + '>';
$(this).children('option').each(function () {
  tmp += '<div class="option"><span class="display">' + $(this).html() + '</span><span class="value">' + $(this).attr('value') + '</span></div>';
});
tmp += '</div>';
tmp += '</div>';

$(this).after(tmp);
$(this).hide();
```

We create the special `div` then hide the `select`

My plugin code (note: It's in CoffeeScript):

```
if this.attr('data-width')
f_width = this.attr('data-width')
tmp = ''
tmp += '<div class="jm-select"' + (if f_width then ' style="width:' + (parseInt(f_width) + 7 + 32) + 'px;"' else '') + '>'
tmp += ' <a ' + (if f_width then ' style = "width:' + parseInt(f_width) + 'px;" ' else ' ') + ' href = "javascript:void(0)" > <span class="display" > ' + display + ' </span><span class="arrow"></span > </a>'
tmp += '<div class="options"' + (if f_width then ' style="width:' + (parseInt(f_width) + 7) + 'px;"' else '') + '>'
this.children('option').each () ->
  tmp += '<div class="option"><span class="display">' + $(this).html() + '</span><span class="value">' + $(this).attr('value') + '</span></div>'
tmp += '</div>'
tmp += '</div>'


this.after(tmp)
this.hide()
```

the `this.hide()` hides both the `select` and the newly created `div` (`this` is now an array).  If I call `this.hide()` before `this.after(tmp)`, it works fine.

Why is `this.hide()` iterating over the new `this` "array" instead of just the `this` `select` object?

**Full plugin code converted from CoffeeScript**

```
var $;

$ = jQuery;

$.fn.jmselect = function() {
  var display, f_width, name, tmp, value;
  name = this.attr('name');
  value = this.val();
  display = this.children("option:selected").text();
  if (this.attr('data-width')) {
    f_width = this.attr('data-width');
  }
  tmp = '';
  tmp += '<div class="jm-select"' + (f_width ? ' style="width:' + (parseInt(f_width) + 7 + 32) + 'px;"' : '') + '>';
  tmp += ' <a ' + (f_width ? ' style = "width:' + parseInt(f_width) + 'px;" ' : ' ') + ' href = "javascript:void(0)" > <span class="display" > ' + display + ' </span><span class="arrow"></span > </a>';
  tmp += '<div class="options"' + (f_width ? ' style="width:' + (parseInt(f_width) + 7) + 'px;"' : '') + '>';
  this.children('option').each(function() {
    return tmp += '<div class="option"><span class="display">' + $(this).html() + '</span><span class="value">' + $(this).attr('value') + '</span></div>';
  });
  tmp += '</div>';
  tmp += '</div>';
  this.hide();
  this.after(tmp);
  this.children("a").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.jm-select').addClass('inactiveSelect');
    $(this).parent('.jm-select').removeClass('inactiveSelect');
    $('.inactiveSelect').children('.options').hide();
    return $(this).parent('.jm-select').children('.options').toggle();
  });
  this.find(".options .option").click(function() {
    var tmp2;
    tmp = $(this).children('span.value').html();
    tmp2 = $(this).children('span.display').html();
    $(this).parent('.options').parent('.jm-select').prev('select').val(tmp).trigger('change');
    $(this).parent('.options').parent('.jm-select').children('a').children('.display').html(tmp2);
    return $('.jm-select').children('.options').hide();
  });
  return this;
};
```

Comment: You need to post **all** of the plugin code, including the function header etc.

Comment: also that code as posted is syntactically incorrect.  It's really important to post **accurate** code that's causing problems - otherwise you just waste time and energy of people trying to help.

Comment: @Pointy - Sorry, it's in CoffeeScript, let me throw up a converted file

Comment: OK - well: you should use `.prop()` to get the "name" property, and `.data()` to get the value of the "data-width" attribute. Also, more fundamentally, the "traditional" structure of a jQuery plugin is to wrap everything in a `.each()` loop, because `this` refers to the entire jQuery object. If your initial selecter picks up multiple elements, then as written your code will do weird things. jQuery does **not** do the `.each()` behavior for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to wrap your plugin behavior in a `.each` loop:

```
$.fn.jmselect = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    // all your stuff here, except the final return
  });
};
```

Comment: This is looking like it could be the right answer, let me play around with it a bit to be sure